# Android studio from eclipse migration

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am having huge problems migrating since I am doing it on a big project.

I have: Beta 0.8.14 installed (latest version)

I generated build.gradle from eclipse and imported to android studio. I tryed running it but there where no modules so after some googleing I tryed adding module but got an error:

```
Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
```

Okey tried again with gradle wrapper and this happend:

```
10:31:24 AssertionError: Already disposed: Module: 'appName': Already disposed: Module: 'appName'
10:31:30 AssertionError: Already disposed: Module: 'appName': Already disposed: Module: 'appName'
```

And now I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to import your project in Android Studio without exporting it in eclipse.

Just import your eclipse-project folder.
This worked for me.

Comment: Tried, not working. :( 
And in the left explorer it doesent find packages and nothing..